# Material Stepper dynamic initialisation with async pipe

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to implement a dynamic stepper where even initial index can be dynamically changed
but the problem is that mat-stepper always initialises with first item.

```
// service.ts
_index$ = new BehaviourSubject<number>(2);
_steps$ = new BehaviourSubject<any[]>([1,2,3,4]);

index$ = this._index$.asObservable();
steps$ = this._steps$.asObservable();

...

// component.html
<mat-horizontal-stepper [selectedIndex]="index$ | async"
                      *ngIf="steps$ | async">
<mat-step *ngFor="let step of steps$ | async">
  Step {{ step }} - {{ index }}
</mat-step>
```

Even though my initial index is set to `2` in BehaviourSubject all I can see is:

```
Step 1 - 2
```

while it should be

```
Step 2 - 2
```

Looks like it picks the correct index but it renders first step.
However, if I do next/previous (set index after initialisation, it works like a charm)